# Excel Calculating Average for every few numbers and skip total

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, average

In excel, I need to calculate average in column B for every few data thats in Column A but need to skip total. But column A doesnt have a consistent sequence. Is it possible to do sth like the picture? I have 100k+ records so doing it manually is not very efficient. Please advise if there a way doing it, thanks

[image]

The logic is that First Average number is based on B2:B6, second average is B8:B11 that is skipping all the "total"

Comment: Consider a different format.  If you assigned an ID to each grouping, you could then use either the SUBTOTAL tool or a Pivot Table to obtain those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH

```
=IF(OR(A1="TOTAL",ROW()=2),AVERAGE(B2:INDEX(B2:B$1040000,MATCH("TOTAL",A2:A$1040000,0)-1)),"")
```

Put that in C2 and copy down the dataset.

Comment: OMG thank you so much! you are expert! I added an extra close Parentheses after -1! and it works perfectly! thanks!!! =IF(OR(A1="TOTAL",ROW()=2),AVERAGE(B2:INDEX(B2:B$1040000,MATCH("TOTAL",A2:A$1040000,0)-1)),"")

Comment: @curios_learaner That is what I get for typing it directly here and not testing it in Excel.